# How to calculate physical address from this assembly instruction?

Tags: assembly, hex, cpu-architecture, microprocessors, hardware

Following are the **register values** for Intel microprocessor:

CX: FF0A

BX: AB5D

DI: BDEF

DX: 1234

DS: CC20

SP: CD0F

**Instruction:**

1. ADD [BX+DI], CX
2. MOV DX, [SP+1652H]

I want to know how to calculate the **physical address** of the above mentioned two instructions.

Comment: It also depends on `ds` for the first instruction. The second instruction is invalid.

Comment: DS is CC20. now please tell me how to calculate the physical addresss?

Comment: well you should mention the ds register's value in the question too. so that readers dont miss it.

Comment: This looks awfully familiar... Didn't someone else ask this homework question last night>?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer this is only third of them... (I wonder how many students are taking that class).  http://stackoverflow.com/q/40568659/4271923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. ADD [BX+DI], CX
You will need to calculate the Effective Address first.

Effective Addressing = Base + Index + Offset

Then, the physical addressing would be: 
Physical Addressing = segmentation * 0x10 + The Effective Addressing

In your case, Base will be the value of bx, index will be the value of di, and offset will be empty. Now calculate by yourself.

Comment: @SaminaJabeen in 16b mode x86 can't encode `[sp + imm16]` memory addressing in any instruction, so technically it's invalid. In 32b mode `[esp + imm32]` would work, so the author of question probably got confused by that. In 16b mode usually the `[bp + imm16]` is used instead (copying `sp` into `bp` at the start of particular part of code), and that's a bit a trick question, as it will not use `ds` as segment register, but other one (just like `esp` in 32b mode would).